# unable to pass post value to second model in code igniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, admin

here is my code, i am trying to have an admin access through the database... but it seems like my usertype validation doesnot get anything. i tried to print_r it and the output is only array(), what do you think is my error. here is my code..

login controller

```
public function loginValidate(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('login_model'); 

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('USERNAME','Username','required|trim|callback_validateCreds');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PASSWORD','Password','required|trim|md5');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        $this->index();

    }else{

        $data = array(

            'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1,
            'value' => $this->login_model->returnQuery()

            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('login/adminIndex');

        $q = $this->login_model->returnQuery();

            if ($q = '1'){

                redirect('login/adminIndex');

            }elseif ($q = '2') {

                redirect('login/userIndex');

            }else{

                redirect('login/restricted');

        }

    }
} 

public function validateCreds(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('login_model');

        if($this->login_model->can_log_in()){ // can_log_in() model

            return true;

        }else{

            $this->form_validation->set_message('validateCreds','Username and password did not match.');  //return message to validateCreds

            return false;
        }

    }
```

here is my models

```
public function can_log_in(){

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
    $data = array(
        'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
        );
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);

    return $query;


    if ($query->num_rows() == 1){

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;
    }

}

public function returnQuery(){


    $sql = "SELECT USERCODE FROM tbl_users where USERNAME =? AND PASSWORD = ?";
    $data = array(
        'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
        );
    $query =  $this->db->query($sql, $data);


    return $query->result();
}
```

does not have any errors but returns true to

```
            if ($q = '1'){

                redirect('login/adminIndex');
```

even if its not = 1.. i also tried == and taking off  '' but it only directs me to the restricted page.

Comment: `=` is not a comparison operator in `if`, it is an assignment operator

Comment: i changed it to == , it just returned true to   ` if ($q == '1'){

                redirect('login/adminIndex');` i am trying to access the other user which is == '2' ...

Comment: and the `print_r($this->login_model->returnQuery());` output is still just array()

Comment: you no need to post in model.. you can simply read the data from $this->input->post() this will give the details in that model too. or you can use $_POST to assign new values that can be read in another model

Comment: redirect won't carry the post data. this becomes another request. Hence you have to keep the data in session to retrieve

Comment: @Sundar so do you suggest that i put my queries in my controllers and not on my models? because i only use the $this->input->post() to put the values of the post() to the query in my models. and i think they are not  getting any values. from my database..

Comment: @Sundar all i wanted to do is to check whether the usertype on my database is == '1' or == '2' so that i would know whether to redirect it to the admin page or the user page. :) please help  me. thank you very much. :)

Comment: redirect('login/adminIndex'); will clear all your post data. so do your updates before redirect

Comment: oh okay. so i just forgot to comment it out!! thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @Sundar it doesnt work. :( i thougt it worked. :( but i did only have typo in my code that it redirected to my userpage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102711/discussion-between-kev-m-and-sundar).

Comment: Y create new question chk answer in old question

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep in mind you are returning the complete array not a single value so change model function as:

```
public function returnQuery(){ 
   $sql = "SELECT USERCODE FROM tbl_users where USERNAME =? AND PASSWORD = ?"; 
   $data = array( 'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'), 'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD') ); 
   $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data); 
   $result = $query->result_array(); 

   if(count($result) > 0){
      return $result[0]["USERCODE"];
   }
   else{
      return 0;
   }
}
```

And than compare value not assign the value:

```
if($q == 1){
   //your redirection stuff
}
elseif($q == 2){
    //your redirection stuff
}
else{
    //your redirection stuff
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

You have also issue in callback function. You are using `return $query` before checking the number of records.

**Modified function**:

```
public function can_log_in(){ 
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?"; 
   $data = array( 'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'), 'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD') ); 
   $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data); 
   //return $query;

   if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
   { 
      return true; 
   }
   else{ 
      return false; 
   } 
}
```